# Restoring Zxing scanner in Windows phone after minimizing in Xamarin

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, zxing, qr-code, xamarin.forms

I have developed a cross platform application in Xamarin(supporting Android,IOS, Windows )

Application is working fine in android and IOS
But in windows , We are minimizing the application after opening the QR scanner, Before scanning the QR code .

On resuming the application we are trying for scanning QR but the camera is not loading. Only the red line of the Scanner is visible

We  are using  Zxing scanner  Library for it